# PostgreSQL installation issue Character Type

Tags: character-encoding, psql, postgresql-9.3

I installed PostgreSQL 9.2 with default database postgres.
It shows Collation and Character Type as en_GB.UTF-8.

Is there any difference between en_GB and en_US. Can I change to en_US without uninstalling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First option is while creating a new database you may provide the Collation and Ctype like

```
postgres=# CREATE DATABASE test  WITH LC_COLLATE='en_US'  Encoding='LATIN1' lc_ctype='en_US' TEMPLATE=template0;;
CREATE DATABASE


postgres=# \l
                                  List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   
-----------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | en_GB.UTF-8 | en_GB.UTF-8 | 
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | en_GB.UTF-8 | en_GB.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | en_GB.UTF-8 | en_GB.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 test      | postgres | LATIN1   | en_US       | en_US       | 
(4 rows)
```

Second option is to do the fresh initdb and provide the -E encoding and --locale=locale. Sets the default locale for the database cluster. If this option is not specified, the locale is inherited from the environment that initdb runs in

See more details about initdb with --locale at [postgres initdb](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/app-initdb.html)

Comment: Is there any  difference between en_GB and en_US, in terms of Ctype. Any idea.

Comment: There is no difference in terms of Ctype. Infact en_US copy en_GB ctype in reality.
see follwoing links for more details: https://lh.2xlibre.net/locale/en_GB/ and https://lh.2xlibre.net/locale/en_US/